# Inclusion of "that" in clauses

Tags: grammar

I would like to know more about the grammartical structure of the two clauses in the following sentence, i.e., "[that] I know" and "that would invalidate it"

> *is there anything I know that would invalidate it?*

"That" is omitted in the first clause. When should one include "that"? Is it true that when the clause includes a subject, one does not need to include "that", whereas when the clause has not subject, the inclusion of "that" is obligatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules you cite are technically correct but phrased a little strange to me. Here is a version of your sentence that includes the word **that**:

> Is there anything that<sub>obj</sub> I know that<sub>subj</sub> would invalidate it?

I have annotated it to show the grammatical roles of each **that**.

The first is the object of the clause **that I know**. In this case, the relative pronoun can be removed because it is the object of the verb **know**.

The second is the subject of the clause **that would invalidate it**. When the relative pronoun is the subject of its clause, it cannot be removed.

I recommend learning the rules this way.

Some people might tell you that removing a pronoun in this way is not appropriate in formal writing. There might be a small amount of truth to that. However, it has been the common practice of journalism for many, many decades—perhaps more than a century.

Comment: how about this sentence"If I ever figure out an angle that I think would be useful to convey, I'll write it up" vs" If I ever figure out an angle I think that would be useful to convey, I'll write it up"? which is correct? Both?

Comment: The first one would be correct: "If I ever figure out an angle that I think would be useful to convey, I'll write it up"